# What is the difference between cross_val_score with scoring='roc_auc' and roc_auc_score?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, cross-validation

I am confused about the difference between the cross_val_score scoring metric 'roc_auc' and the roc_auc_score that I can just import and call directly.

The documentation (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter) indicates that specifying scoring='roc_auc' will use the sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score. However, when I implement GridSearchCV or cross_val_score with scoring='roc_auc' I receive very different numbers that when I call roc_auc_score directly.

Here is my code to help demonstrate what I see:

```
# score the model using cross_val_score

rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=150,
                            min_samples_leaf=4,
                            min_samples_split=3,
                            n_jobs=-1)

scores = cross_val_score(rf, X, y, cv=3, scoring='roc_auc')

print scores
array([ 0.9649023 ,  0.96242235,  0.9503313 ])

# do a train_test_split, fit the model, and score with roc_auc_score

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

print roc_auc_score(y_test, rf.predict(X_test))
0.84634039111363313 # quite a bit different than the scores above!
```

I feel like I am missing something very simple here -- most likely a mistake in how I am implementing/interpreting one of the scoring metrics.

Can anyone shed any light on the reason for the discrepancy between the two scoring metrics?

Comment: I am also totally confused by this difference. I also tried using the standard make_scorer() function that turn a score function into a correct Scorer object for cross_val_score, but the results are the same. make_scorer() gives the same result as my manual implementation, while 'roc_auc' gives higher scores. Fortunately the difference was several % in my example, unlike your, but still: which function should I trust?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because you supplied predicted y's instead of the probability in roc_auc_score. This function takes a score, not the classified label. Try instead to do this:

```
print roc_auc_score(y_test, rf.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1])
```

It should give a similar result to previous result from cross_val_score. [Refer to this post for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318922/scikit-learn-roc-auc-score-returns-accuracy-values).

Comment: You are completely right! I'd laugh if I could stop crying. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33641088/unexpected-cross-validation-scores-with-scikit-learn-linearregression). The key takeaway there was that `cross_val_score` uses the [`KFold`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.KFold.html) strategy with default parameters for making the train-test splits, which means splits into consecutive chunks rather than shuffling. `train_test_split` on the other hand does a shuffled split.

The solution is to make the split strategy explicit and specify shuffling, like this:

```
shuffle = cross_validation.KFold(len(X), n_folds=3, shuffle=True)
scores = cross_val_score(rf, X, y, cv=shuffle, scoring='roc_auc')
```

Comment: Aniket, thanks for the answer. But specifying the folds and passing them into cross_val_score did not address the discrepancy between the scoring metrics.

Comment: I know I'm very late to this, but when you use the `cross_val_score` method with the `roc_auc` scoring, why do you pass it the predicted class labels instead of predicted probabilities? Since it's AUC, doesn't it need probabilities instead, so it can test different threshold values?

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this problem myself and after digging a bit found the answer. Sharing for the love.

There is actually two and a half problems.

1. you need to use the same Kfold to compare scores (the same split of the train/test);
2. you need to feed the probabilities into the `roc_auc_score` (using the `predict_proba()` method). BUT, some estimators (like SVC) does not have a `predict_proba()` method, you then use the `decision_function()` method.

Here's a full example:

```
# Let's use the Digit dataset
digits = load_digits(n_class=4)
X,y = digits.data, digits.target
y[y==2] = 0 # Increase problem dificulty
y[y==3] = 1 # even more
```

Using two estimators

```
LR = LogisticRegression()
SVM = LinearSVC()
```

Split the train/test set. But keep it into a variable we can reuse.

```
fourfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=4, random_state=4)
```

Feed it to `GridSearchCV` and save scores. Note we are passing `fourfold`.

```
gs = GridSearchCV(LR, param_grid={}, cv=fourfold, scoring='roc_auc', return_train_score=True)
gs.fit(X,y)
gs_scores = np.array([gs.cv_results_[k][0] for k in gskeys])
```

Feed it to `cross_val_score` and save scores.

```
 cv_scores = cross_val_score(LR, X, y, cv=fourfold, scoring='roc_auc')
```

Sometimes, you want to loop and compute several different scores, so this is what you use.

```
loop_scores = list()
for idx_train, idx_test in fourfold.split(X, y):
  X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = X[idx_train], y[idx_train], X[idx_test], y[idx_test]
  LR.fit(X_train, y_train)
  y_prob = LR.predict_proba(X_test)
  auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_prob[:,1])
  loop_scores.append(auc)
```

Do we have the same scores across the board?

```
print [((a==b) and (b==c)) for a,b,c in zip(gs_scores,cv_scores,loop_scores)]
>>> [True, True, True, True]
```

---

BUT, sometimes our estimator does not have a `predict_proba()` method. So, according to this [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/calibration/plot_calibration_curve.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-calibration-plot-calibration-curve-py), we do this:

```
for idx_train, idx_test in fourfold.split(X, y):
  X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = X[idx_train], y[idx_train], X[idx_test], y[idx_test]
  SVM.fit(X_train, y_train)
  y_prob = SVM.decision_function(X_test)
  prob_pos = (y_prob - y_prob.min()) / (y_prob.max() - y_prob.min())
  auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, prob_pos)
```