# different roc_auc with XGBoost gridsearch scoring='roc_auc' and roc_auc_score?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost, grid-search

I've used GridSearch for classification problem:

```
# A parameter grid for XGBoost
params = {
        'min_child_weight': [1, 5, 10],
        'gamma': [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 5],
        'subsample': [0.6, 0.8, 1.0],
        'colsample_bytree': [0.6, 0.8, 1.0],
        'max_depth': [3, 4, 5]
        }
# fit model no training data

xgb = XGBClassifier(learning_rate=0.02, n_estimators=600, 
objective='binary:logistic',
                silent=True, nthread=1)
folds = 3
param_comb = 5

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=folds, shuffle = True, random_state = 1001)

random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(xgb, param_distributions=params, 
                                   n_iter=param_comb, scoring='roc_auc', 
                                   n_jobs=4,

cv=skf.split(X_train_resampled,y_train_resampled), verbose=3, 
                                   random_state=1001 )
random_search.fit(X_train_resampled, y_train_resampled)

print('\n Best hyperparameters:')
print(random_search.best_params_)
print('\n Best estimator:')
print(random_search.best_estimator_)
```

after that i've got :

> Best hyperparameters: {'subsample': 0.6, 'min_child_weight': 1,
>   'max_depth': 5, 'gamma': 1.5, 'colsample_bytree': 0.8}
>
> Best estimator: XGBClassifier(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree',
>   colsample_bylevel=1,
>          colsample_bytree=0.8, gamma=1.5, learning_rate=0.02,
>          max_delta_step=0, max_depth=5, min_child_weight=1, missing=None,
>          n_estimators=600, n_jobs=1, nthread=1, objective='binary:logistic',
>          random_state=0, reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1,
>          seed=None, silent=True, subsample=0.6)

The best ROC AUC was score=0.9719630276538562. Than i've ran classifier:

```
model=XGBClassifier(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', colsample_bylevel=1,
       colsample_bytree=0.8, gamma=1.5, learning_rate=0.02,
       max_delta_step=0, max_depth=5, min_child_weight=1, missing=None,
       n_estimators=600, n_jobs=4, objective='binary:logistic',
       random_state=0, reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1,
       seed=None, silent=True, subsample=0.6)

model.fit(X_train_resampled, y_train_resampled)
# make predictions for test data    
predictions = model.predict_proba(X_test_scaled)[:, 1]
# evaluate predictions
print ('ROC AUC Score',roc_auc_score(y_test,predictions))
```

I've read the closest topic ([What is the difference between cross_val_score with scoring='roc_auc' and roc_auc_score?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33642158/what-is-the-difference-between-cross-val-score-with-scoring-roc-auc-and-roc-au)), but  the problem remains. I've used predict_proba and got ROC AUC Score 0.791423604769.

Why is such difference? Any suggestion? before start classifier i'm making scaling and resampling but with fixed random state - the same as for gridsearch.

Comment: RandomizedSearchCV will split the `X_train_resampled, y_train_resampled` into train and test according to the `cv` provided, and the best_score_ you see is the mean score of test data on all folds. But below you are calculating the scores on `X_test_scaled` which I assume is separate from `X_train_resampled`. Maybe thats the source of difference.

Comment: Moreover, the score 0.99 seems too high, and thats because you have resampled the data and then RandomizedSearchCV is splitting that into train and test, so its leaking the information of test data into the model. I would advise you to use a Pipeline with Sampling and XGB, so that data is split first into train and test and then only train data is resampled.

Comment: @VivekKumar, thank you, i think you right, after disabling the leak ROC AUC become stable!  and i try not to use resampling and got higher ROC AUC